# CustomElementRegistry.whenDefined returns void instead of the constructor

Tags: javascript, custom-element

assume a custom elment being defined and using `CustomElements.whenDefined` function to check when that happes:

```
customElements.whenDefined("foo-bar").then(console.log)

customElements.define("foo-bar", class {});
```

according to the Custom elments spec (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#dom-customelementregistry-whendefined) and in MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) the `CustomElements.whenDefined` will be resolved with the CustomElement's Constructor. But when running the code above in chrome(86) or firefox(82) it logs `undefined`. Microsoft's type definition for this method (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blame/2d495b7f251511ba00bc0e3311de2090f92e79dd/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3513) also resolves it with "void".

(`customElements.get("foo-bar")` does work correctly and returns the constructors.)

Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Good question for: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues